# How to change the labels of the choices in an option menu?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, tkinter

I have a Tkinter option menu like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

choices = [1,2,3]

GUI = tk.Tk()
var2set = tk.IntVar(GUI)
tk.OptionMenu(GUI, var2set, *choices).grid(column=0, row=0)
GUI.mainloop()
```

Is it possible to change the labels of the choices `[1,2,3]` to strings like `"title 1", "title 2", "title 3"` **WITHOUT** a modification of the variable `choices`? It is important, that each option in the option menu delivers the chosen integer value from the choices-list.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  If you just want it to display something like `Title 1` instead of a numeric just make that change.  You can then make python do whatever you want when that is selected by the user. Doesn't matter what the title is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I fully understood what you are asking for then 
Yes I think dictionary can be used here but as you said you want the contents of `choices` not to be disturbed then you can find this useful..

```
import Tkinter as tk

def select():
    title=var.get()
    print "selected string :"+title
    print "corresponing integer value :"+str(choices[Dic[title]])


choices = [1,2,3]
Dic={'title 1':0,'title 2':1,'title 3':2}
GUI = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar(GUI)
var.set('title 1')
op=tk.OptionMenu(GUI, var, *Dic.keys())
op.pack(side='left',padx=20,pady=10)
bt=tk.Button(GUI,text='check value',command=select)
bt.pack(side='left',padx=20,pady=10)
GUI.mainloop()
```

The indexing is quite messy but may be its exactly the way you want it
Also you can make dictionary of any length(same as of `choices`) using trivial loops that's too obvious :)

Comment: Principally this is exactly the way I am looking for. It makes the option menu look like I want. But the problem is that var2set.get() gives me the string-values from the dictionary and not the associated integers. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: I have edited the answer may be this is what you need